# How can I determine $A, B, C, D, K$ from subspace? System identification

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, control-theory, parameter-estimation, system-identification

Assume that we want to find this model:

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k) + Ke(k)\\
y(k) = Cx(k) + Du(k)$$

And we want to set it up in this problem form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x(1) & x(2) & x(3) & \dots & x(n+1)\\ 
y(0) & y(1) & y(2) & \dots &y(n)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
= \begin{bmatrix}
A & B &K \\ 
C & D & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x(0) & x(1) & x(2) & \dots & x(n)\\
u(0) & u(1) & u(2) & \dots &u(n)\\
e(0) & e(1) & e(2) & \dots & e(n)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**What we know:**

We know the dimensions of $A, B, C, D, K$ and the length $n$ and we know the dimensions of $x(k), u(k), y(k), e(k)$. We also have $u(k), y(k), e(k)$ as our data. They are fully known.

**What we don't know:**

We don't know the values of $A, B, C, D, K, x(k)$

**What we want to know:**

We want to know the values of $A, B, C, D, K$

**Question:**

How can we find $A, B, C, D, K$ if we only know the dimensions of all matrices and vectors and the values of the data vectors $u(k), y(k), e(k)$?

Comment: You also have to assert assumptions about your definition of $x(k)$, because otherwise there is no unique solution for this problem due to similarity transformations.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I don't know any assumptions about $x(k)$, except they all are real numbers.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Do you know one system ID method that can estimate kalman filter gain if noise is known?

Comment: One way you could define the state is $x(k)=\begin{bmatrix}y(k)^\top & y(k-1)^\top & \cdots & y(k-m)^\top\end{bmatrix}^\top$. Though, if the number of outputs is larger than one then it might not be possible to get a state vector of the same length as the dimensions of $A$.

Comment: Since you known $e(k)$ you could also use $u_{new}(k) = \begin{bmatrix}u(k)^\top & e(k)^\top\end{bmatrix}^\top$ with $B_{new} = \begin{bmatrix}B & K\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there are two different ways to perform system identification with state space systems:

1. The Expectation-Maximization algorithm (EM), which is an iterative method to find (local) maximum likelihood or maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimates of parameters in statistical models, where the model depends on unobserved latent variables (cf [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm)).
2. The subspace method, in which observations are stacked as a Hankel matrix and decomposed using singular value decomposition to read out the matrices of the system.

Both methods are reviewed in the [BRML textbook](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Brml.HomePage) (Chapter 24.5.3) accessible online.